# Best translation - "Live Deliberately" - vive de industria? vive deliberate? vive consilium?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, word-comparison

What would the best translation of "Live Deliberately" be as a motto?  I'm thinking of a few different phrases: vive de industria? vive deliberate? vive consilium?  Not sure what is best.

This is a quote from Thoreau "I went to the woods because I wished to live deliberately, to front only the essential facts of life, and see if I could not learn what it had to teach, and not, when I came to die, discover that I had not lived."

Thanks!

Comment: Strangely enough, this site has [already known](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18458/how-would-i-translate-i-went-to-the-woods-so-that-when-i-came-to-die-i-did-not) a request to translate that opening line but specifically with "*Live Deliberately*" part omitted.

Comment: Haha I hadn't come across that... I feel demand to "Live Deliberately" is the most important part!